# Using Core Location in Apple WatchKit

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm currently developing an apple watch extension. Anybody knows if the current location is provided by iPhone or Watch itself?
I can't find any information about this and i need to draw a compass pointing where the watch is pointing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do what you want you don't need CoreLocation you just need a magnetometer.

AFAIK the Apple Watch doesn't have one built in.

The sensors it has are...

- Accelerometer
- Gyroscope
- Heart rate sensor
- Barometer

No magnetometer though.

Comment: The watchkit extension runs inside the iphone, so you can get the location using that using the conventional means.

Comment: @PeterSmith They don't want the location though. They want the direction of North. I do t think there's a way of detecting the phone direction compared to the watch direction.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, you are quite right, I didn't analyze what the problem was he was trying to solve, just answered the question. The watch would require an internal compass, I haven't come across one. The best that could be done by the watch I believe is knowing what way the phone is pointing.

Comment: The "Maps" section of this page shows a heading arrow, which makes me wonder if there might be one and they just haven't exposed it yet: https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/ui-elements/

Comment: @gohnjanotis that isn't a heading arrow. That's a graphic showing what they mean in the text. The watch doesn't have a compass.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple's Dev Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/iOSSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH21-SW1)

The best solution for performing any long-running tasks is to let your iOS app perform the task instead. For example, instead of starting location services in your WatchKit extension, start it in your iOS app. Your iOS app can gather the needed data and put it in a shared app group so that your extension can access it later. Use the openParentApplication:reply: method to initiate tasks and receive a reply or use a shared group container to communicate details between your iOS app and WatchKit extension. For information about how to handle communication between your iOS app and WatchKit extension, see Communicating Directly with Your Containing iOS App.

P.S. I am working on similar app.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use CoreLocation from the watchkit extension.  You can however use an api to open the parent app (in the background) and ask your parent api for the information. The api is really nice because you can use it with a reply so that you can easily get the information back:

```
+ (BOOL)openParentApplication:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error)) reply;    // launches containing iOS application on the phone
```

Comment: CoreLocation can be used from a WatchKit extension, however it can't prompt for permissions and inherits the container app's location permissions.
`openParentApplication:` is difficult to use the way you're describing, because the response needs to be synchronous, but CoreLocation is an async API.

Comment: @Sam `openParentApplication:reply:` is asynchronous — your app can call the callback at any time.

Comment: @Sidnicious right, it’s async. Not sure if I’d fully grokked the Beta 2 changes at the time - sorry.

Comment: My watchOS 1 app uses CoreLocation because it runs on the iPhone.  So I really don't know where you are getting your information from.

A CoreLocation subset is also supported running natively with watchOS 2.