# WatchKit and Geolocation

Tags: swift, ios8, geolocation, watchkit

I'm writing an application for Apple Watch on Swift. And my aim is to create a sort of navigator, which could show you the length between your current position and a point on the map. At the moment I'm trying to get my current position and display it on the screen but unfortunately the code does not work.

Here is the code of InterfaceController.swift file.

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblLocationDisplay: WKInterfaceLabel!;

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager();

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }
    @IBAction func btnFindLocation() {
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation();

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
            println("Something");
                let placeMarks = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark;
                self.displayLocation(placeMarks);

        });
    }

    func displayLocation(placemark: CLPlacemark) {
//        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation();
        println(placemark.country);
        let locality = placemark.locality;
        let postalCode = placemark.postalCode;
        let administrativeArea = placemark.administrativeArea;
        let country = placemark.country;

        lblLocationDisplay.setText("Locality: \(locality) PostalCode: \(postalCode) Area: \(administrativeArea) Country: \(country)");
    }
}
```

Here is the [project](https://github.com/patut/GeoLocation-ins-Swift-for-WatchKit)

Please, share your suggestions of the reason why the code does not work. And also I wish you could advice me how to realize a navigator App in the watches. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take the current user location, you should follow this step:
- Add CoreLocation framework to libraries off IOS app. 
- In supporting file folder of IOS app, and info.plist file, you should add two row with name :
NSLocationWhenInUseDescription and value you can set "To know your locaton!!"
and another row:
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and value you can set "Always using location!"
- Now import CoreLocation to view controller.swift and add a delegate of CLLocationDelegate.

Now in watchkit extension, you should import CoreLocation and CLLocationManager Delegate too and follow this step in awakeWithContext :

```
//Make a new locationManager variable:

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        //        set delegate
        locationManager.delegate = self
        //        Set desiredAccuracy using a GPS of IP:
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        //        request to use location

        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        //        start update location
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

after that you write the CLLocationManagerDelegate:

```
// MARK: CLLocationManagerDelegate

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        println(locations)
    }
```

Note that you have run your IOS app first to accept to take a location of the user, after that you can run Watchkit scheme to take the current User Location.

Comment: "Add CoreLocation framework to libraries off IOS app" - Sorry, but where exactly should I add this? I have 4 info.plist)

"and add a delegate of CLLocationDelegate" - should it be like this "var delegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate?"? I'm a little bit confusing(

Comment: I don't know why, but the app does not run on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use request always access instead of request when in use.  See this post [How to calculate current location in WatchKit extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960108/how-to-calculate-current-location-in-watchkit-extension/27964325#27964325) for more on use CLLocationManger in a WatchKit extension.