# How to get the current location in a WatchKit app?

Tags: ios, location, core-location, watchkit

If I'm not wrong, the `App Watch` can't take locations itself and needs to request it to the `iPhone`, so the current location is got in the `WatchKit` extension at iOS side... right?

I think this is a quite common thing `WatchKit` developers would do, but I don't find a clear tutorial/example of it, could somebody tell me one or post me some code? In addition, do you know if the way to deal with locations changes in `watchOS 2`?

**EDIT:** I've found that in some posts it is said that `CoreLocation` can be accessed from the `WatchKit` extension, and in others I've read that only the `iOS` app can... which is the correct?

Comment: may be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960108/how-to-calculate-current-location-in-watchkit-extension) helps with you

Answer (score 1):

You can access `CoreLocation` and all its methods directly from `WatchKit` itself. There's no need to employ any sort of additional logic, such as opening the parent app.

In **watchOS 1**, your WatchKit app is technically running on the iPhone, and you can therefore use *(almost)* any frameworks available to you on the iPhone (such as `CoreLocation`).

In **watchOS 2**, the WatchKit app is running on the Watch itself. I have done some research and I've not found anything that indicates you will have to make any changes to your usage of `CoreLocation`, and I will therefore assume the frameworks automatically handle the communication between the iPhone and the Watch. 
I'll update this answer if I find anything indicating that you will have to employ some other logic to make this work in watchOS 2.